# If $\lVert \cdot \rVert \leq \lVert \cdot \rVert'$ are two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, what would be the relation of the corresponding operator norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite-dimensional, all norms are equivalent on it. Thus, all operator norms of $T$ must be equivalent as well.

However, I would like to know more details. That is, if $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert'$ are two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lVert v \rVert < \lVert v \rVert'
\end{equation}
except for $v=0$, then is there any definite relation between $\lVert T \rVert_{op}$ and $\lVert T \rVert'_{op}$?

Here, $\lVert T \rVert_{op}:=\sup_{v \neq 0} \frac{\lVert Tv \rVert}{\lVert v \rVert}$ and similarly for $\lVert T \rVert'_{op}$.

The fraction appearing in the definition of the operator norm prevents me from making a conclusion. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You can avoid  fractions $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\|Tx\|.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\frac1c ||\cdot || \le || \cdot ||' \le c ||\cdot||$ with $c > 0$. Then
$$\frac{||Tv||'}{||v||'} \le \frac{c||Tv||}{\frac1c ||v||} \le c^2 \frac{||Tv||}{||v||}.$$
Taking supremum, $||T||_{\text{op}}' \le c^2 ||T||_{\text{op}}$. By symmetry,
$\frac1{c^2} ||T||_{\text{op}} \le ||T||_{\text{op}}' \le c^2 ||T||_{\text{op}}$.